# Where can I find the list of available properties for SPNavigationNode?

Tags: 2010, development, publishing

In SharePoint 2010 (as well as other versions) with Publishing enabled, you have an SPWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar object. This represents the links you see in the Top Link Bar, and is a collection of SPNavigationNode objects. One of the properties of SPNavigationNode is "Properties", a Hashtable. An example Property is "NodeType". Since it's a Hashtable, there can be one, zero, or many Properties for each Node. My question is, where do I find a list of the common Properties used?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any official documentation about that. After decompiling DLLs, this is what I found :

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode.Properties` are coming from `SPRequest.GetNavigationNodeProperties`

The latter gets those properties from an internal class, which seems to point to `OWSSRV.dll` that I cannot decompile.

See also : [Decompiling SharePoint - Finding "extern" Function Implementations](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85821/decompiling-sharepoint-finding-extern-function-implementations)

Your best bet would be to get the properties from different objects and check for yourself what is returned. Or try searching the Internet for that subject and gather what you can from different sources.

Comment: I have found a few other instances, such as Audience and Target. I was hoping to find a definitive list from Microsoft. The different values of NodeType ("Heading", "Area", etc.) are listed on MSDN. I know using Reflection you can return all the properties of a class. But I don't think there is a way in code you can get the values of a hashtable, since each Node will have different values.